# Negative number in bash shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, math

I need some help with a bash mathematical expression script. I need the expression below to be a negative 2 to the power of 63 but I have tried all sorts of combinations from "", '', (()) and even keeping the positive value but multiplying it by -1 but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Original expression:

```
kw=`expr 2^63 | bc`
```

gives me 9223372036854775808 (which is correct) but I need to get a -9223372036854775808.

I want to be able to do a kw=`expr -2^63 | bc` to get a negative results but it's not as straight-forward as I'd hoped. Hence my numerous attempts of different permutations to the expression.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$ kw=$(echo -2^63 | bc)
$ echo $kw
-9223372036854775808
```

**UPDATE**

[@DigitalTrauma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2113226/digitaltrauma) is right, if you're in `bash`, then using a [bash here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) is better (one less process, more efficient):

```
kw=$(bc <<< -2^63)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Janos. Superman stuff with your fast response time :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you don't even need the `echo`; you can use a [bash here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) instead:

```
$ kw=$(bc <<< -2^63)
$ echo $kw
-9223372036854775808
```